# Fragment Replaced even then Getting touch Events of Replaced Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment

I have an Activity with 3 fragments at different positions A,B,C

When i replaced my fragment C with one fragment D. I am still getting the touch events of the fragment C. Where i will be getting Wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I know that one way to implement swappable fragments is to attach them to a FrameLayout. Is it possible that you have setup your fragments to listen for click events on the FrameLayout and forgotten to disconnect the inactive fragment?

Comment: Yes i am taking the reference of the C fragment in my activity. How to  inactive that thing ?. Actually i do not under stand the "forgotten to disconnect the inactive fragment?"